# Not able to convert IST [Asia/Calcutta] to AET [Australia/Sydney] using ZoneDateTime in Java8

Tags: java, timezone

I am trying to convert a **LocalDateTime** which is in IST [Asia/Calcutta] to **AET [Australia/Sydney]** using `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. Below is what I did:

```
LocalDateTime ldt    = LocalDateTime.now();
ZoneDateTime  zdt    = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney"));

System.out.println( ldt.toString() + " -- " + ZoneDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
System.out.printlb( zdt + " -- " + ZoneDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney")));
```

The above code gives me the following result:

```
2016-09-23T22:53:55.790 -- 2016-09-23T22:53:55.790+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
2016-09-23T22:57:50.855+10:00[Australia/Sydney] -- 2016-09-24T03:27:50.854+10:00[Australia/Sydney]
```

As you can see from the above result that `zdt` and `ZoneDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney"))` gives me different date an Time.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please post compilable code.

Comment: Also, it's unclear to me what you're asking. You're taking the local time, `22:53`, and saying "give me that time as a `ZonedDateTime` in Sydney".  That's still `22:53` but in Sydney. But the time in Sydney isn't `22:53` right now, it's `03:27`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) doesn't have a time zone, so when you call [`atZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-), it's interpreted as being in the zone you're applying:

> This returns a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) formed from this date-time at the specified time-zone.

To actually convert the time, it needs to know the original zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta"));
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = zdt1.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney"));
System.out.println(zdt1); // prints: 2016-09-23T23:10:00.678+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
System.out.println(zdt2); // prints: 2016-09-24T03:40:00.678+10:00[Australia/Sydney]
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.